# Why is Entity Framework ignoring existing GUIDs on insert?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

I have a table defined in Sql Server with a GUID primary key and a default of newsequentialid():

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[mything](
    [id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [foo] [varchar][32] NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_mything] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [id] ASC
    )
)
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[mything]
ADD CONSTRAINT [DF_mything_id]
DEFAULT (newsequentialid()) FOR [id]
GO
```

And when I add an entity with the guid primary key already set, it ends up as a record in the database with a new guid primary key.

```
var anEntity = new mything
{
    id = "17870C25-FC04-EB11-80E9-000C29F38B54",
    foo = "Some stuff",
}

dbContext.mythings.Add(anEntity);
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

EF seems to ignore the guid that was provided in the record and writes the record with a new Guid.

What I would expect is that the record provided had a null guid, it would be populated with a new guid, and if it was not null it would be used unchanged. But that's not what I'm seeing happen.

I'm seeing duplicate records, with different GUIDs, instead of primary key violation exceptions, because the GUIDs I'm providing in my EF entities are being ignored.

Why could this be happening?

Please tell me this isn't by design!

===

OK, this does seem to be by design.

First, this isn't in SQL server.  If I try to insert a record with the id field set, it inserts, or fails with a primary key failure if there is already a record with that id. It only creates a new GUID for the id field if the provided id field is null.

But in EF, the value in the id field is ignored, and a new GUID is generated every time.

It was suggested to me that EF was behaving this way so as to follow the same pattern as when using autoincrement keys. And that does seem to be the case.

In SQL Server, if you try to provide a value to an autoincrement key field on an insert, you get an error:

```
Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table
```

But in EF, the value you provide is ignored, and a new value is generated.

So in this respect, Entity Framework is consistent. Consistently wrong, but consistent.

Answer (score 0):

First step I'd look at to narrow this down is to capture a Profiler/Extended Event trace at the database to see exactly what EF is sending to the database.

Your expectation of the database behaviour is correct - so I'd want to understand where it is breaking down first